# Stopping Embedded Vimeo Player Asking for VR Permissions

Tags: javascript, vimeo-player

I've got an embedded Vimeo player on my website, using the Player SDK that Vimeo provides. Something I have noticed is that on Firefox, whenever I visit the site, I am prompted to give Vimeo access to any virtual reality devices attached.

As this prompt is rather instrusive, is there anyway to prevent Vimeo asking for this permission?

For reference, this is the iframe code that I am using to embed the player:

```html
<iframe #videoPlayer src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/(id)" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send the [HTTP `Feature-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy), you can manually override the nested frame.

One or both of the following headers should do the trick:

```
Feature-Policy: vr none

Permissions-Policy: xr-spatial-tracking=()
```